# Need help on looping through this state and showing the props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that i want to reuse by passing the state as props, but i need to loop through the state first and get the values. I tried using object.keys() but i think im doing something wrong.

Heres my state:

```
const [savingSources, setSavingSources] = useState({
    exams: {
      name: "Your Exams",
      checked: false,
      loading: false,
      savings: []
    },
    pharmacy: {
      name: "Farmácias",
      checked: false,
      loading: false,
      savings: []
    },
    pagVolta: {
      name: "PagVolta",
      checked: false,
      loading: false,
      savings: []
    }
  });
```

And here's where i try to loop, but im unable to get the values inside each key

```
  {Object.keys(savingSources).map((source, index) => {
        return (
          <SavingInformation
            key={index}
            name={source.name}
            checked={source.checked}
            savings={source.savings}
            loading={source.loading}            
          />
        );
      })}
```

Everything besides the source var returns undefined and i tried passing only the source and then getting the props on the component but it only returns the name that is stored on 'source'.

Im very new to React and i wanted this approach because im trying to make reusable components, but im stuck trying to figure this out.

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: @BrianThompson everyprops that i pass that comes from source returns undefined, when i console.log(source) it returns : exams, pharmacy and pagVolta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Object keys is going to return an array of the object fields. You will need to use these fields/keys to access the object values inside map.

```
{Object.keys(savingSources).map((key, index) => {
    return (
      <SavingInformation
        key={index}
        name={savingSources[key].name}
        checked={savingSources[key].checked}
        savings={savingSources[key].savings}
        loading={savingSources[key].loading}            
      />
    );
  })}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @varoons, that was exactly what i needed

Answer (score 0):

Object.keys will only give you the first level keys of the object (e.g. : exams, pharmacy, pagVolta). You can then use those keys to access the state like `savingSources[source]['name']`